# SQLite requests using IONIC

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do SQLite requests (INSERT and SELECT * FROM TABLE) using IONIC. I seek your help...

1) I create a database :

```
createDatabaseFile() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: DATABASE_FILENAME,
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.db = db;
        //Create table 'favories':
        this.createTable("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favories ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, cityNameFavory VARCHAR(100) );");
        console.log('DB well created.');
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

The createTable method is below:

```
 createTable(sqlInstruction) {
    this.db.executeSql(sqlInstruction, {})
    .then(
      () => {
      console.log('OK : ' + sqlInstruction);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

2) I add a city as favory using addFavorite(city) method which is called from .html :

```
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cityName" placeholder="Add a city..."></ion-input>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addFavorite(cityName)">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
```

I can get the cityName in console.log but I did'nt success to insert this city in my table.
Please find below the addFavorite method:

```
addFavorite(city) {
    this.db.executeSql("INSERT INTO favories (cityNameFavory) VALUES(?);", {city})
    .then(() => {
      alert('Ville ajoutée !');
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

  }
```

3) I can't retrieve my data when I use "SELECT x FROM", even if I well retrieve the number of lines:

```
getData() {
    this.db.executeSql("SELECT cityNameFavory FROM favories;", {})
    .then((data) => {
      if(data == null) {
        alert("Empty!")
            }

            if(data.rows) {
        console.log("Number of lines = " + data.rows.length);

                if(data.rows.length > 0) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.listFavories.push(data.rows.item(i).cityNameFavory);
            alert(this.listFavories[i]);
          }

        }
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

And :

```
public listFavories: string[] = [];
```

Please find below my details:

**cli packages:**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

**global packages:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

**local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

**System:**

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v7.9.0
npm               : 4.2.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I modified my code as below:

```
this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO `table` (cityName) VALUES(\'' + city + '\')', {})
    .then(() => {
      console.log("City added");
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```